# Incorporate 3rd Party Native Libs into Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to setup an NDK library module structured very similar to the gen-libs module in the [Android-NDK sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs).  It identifies what I want in an Android NDK library module to allow me to incorporate 3rd party Native Libs:

- src/main/cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
- Android manifest
- build.gradle

I am NOT looking to add C or C++ source files to my app module.

Instead, I am looking to create an Android-NDK library module within Android Studio, so that I can incorporate 3rd Party Native Libs.
However, I am Unable to easily reproduce the structure of the gen-libs module in Android-NDK sample hello-libs.
More specifically,  Android Studio does not provide any option to create a "New => Module => Android Library => Add NDK/C++ support"

I suppose I can recreate this NDK module manually, but before I do that, I would like to ask the community if, for a brand new project, is there any easy way to auto-create the gen-libs module structure from hello-libs beside manual method?

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to use your copy/paste skills to produce the project manually. The wizard won't do it for you, at least for now.

You can also create an app project and switch it to library by changing one line in **build.gradle**.

You can also create a library module, right click on this module, and choose 'Link C++ Project with Gradle' from the popup menu (or from File menu).

Comment: ah yes, I was studying the app project wizard, checking the "C++ support" option gave me everything I wanted, thanks for the tip about the one-liner!